# How can i do perspective transformation in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glut

If i have common style perspective transformation matrix like this

```
/ focus    0    cx \
|  0     focus  cy |
\  0       0     1 /
```

how can setup parameters for glFrustum or gluPerspective to get correct transformation

*for example:*

```
glFrustum ( -cx, screenWidth - cx, -cy, screenHeight - cy, focus, focus + 1000)
gluLookAt( 0.0, 0.0, -focus,   0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

don't create correct transformation =(

Comment: can you explain what you call a "common style perspective transformation matrix" ?

Comment: opposite to oblique perspective, I presume

Comment: matrix listed below P = ((focus, 0 cx),(0,focus,cy),(0,0,1))
where perspective transformation write as: (x,y,1) = P*R*T(X,Y,Z,1) 

I will try to reformulate the question. If I know focal length of camera and coorinates of principal point (point of intersection of main optical axis (Z) and projection plane). How should I call the method glFrustum to perfom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it!!! =) Maybe someone it will be useful

```
glFrustum( -znear*cx / fx, znear*(w - cx) / fx,
           -znear*cy / fy, znear*(h - cy) / fy, 
            znear, zfar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glFrustum ( 0, screenWidth ,0, screenHeight, focus, focus + 1000)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLookAt(...)
```

But the given matrix is not a 4D transformation matrix as expected by openGL; you should check out http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrustum.xml

And you are setting your near clipping plane at "focus", so anything closed will be clipped ! You should choose a more decent value, like 1.0. focus+1000 makes sense, though

Comment: This is exactly equivalent transformation?! i don't see any perspertive  distortion... projected lines looks like perallel =(

and where should i setup camera principal point (cx,cy)?

Comment: You should use gluPerspective instead of glFrustum, it will be simpler to setup. What do you call "camera principal point" ? in openGL the camera is always at (0,0,0), pointing towards -Z (in world space).